# Why does the shoulder deform when rigging its arm?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, mixamo

Is it the body mesh that is the issue or the way it is being rigged? I am only new to rigging and doing animations so I hope that I am doing something wrong with the rig itself for it to make it look like that. The shoulder looks highly unrealistic when moving the arm around.

All I did was move the right hand down via the z axis.

[image]

[image]

Here is my blender file.
[image]

Comment: This is an issue with weights and bone placement (and unapplied transforms, probably.)  Your file complicates it because you started rigging (constraints and controls) before checking weights and positions.  I started on an answer but stopped when I realized you had a bunch of non-deforming bones, which makes it a pain to tell you what to do.  Get good weights and bone positions, then get controls and constraints afterwards.